# Jhipster ParentDTO does not have list of Child DTO

Tags: jhipster, jdl

am generating enties some thing like below, Person

```
entity Employee {
    firstName String
    lastName String
}

entity Role {
    Name String
}

relationship OneToMany {
    Employee{role} to Role{employee required}
}
```

The generated Employee does not include the RoleDTO. I would like it to return the following:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "roles": 
            [
                {
                    "id": 1                    
                    "name": "Admin"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2
                    "name": "Collector"
                }
            ]   
}
```

But the DTO generated are working other ways round.
Role is having List of EmployeeDTO's.
Manual Code change is one option,but in my project i have alsmot 40 entities and this mdoification has to be done for almost all entities. In that case Jhispter is generated code is not usefull any more.

Comment: If you don't want to do it manually, write a blueprint

Comment: @GaëlMarziou thanks for the quick response. do we have existing such blueprints ?

Comment: No, you got to write one yourself, see https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/creating-a-blueprint/